# Swift: Detect if a property is a variable or a constant

Tags: swift, properties, mirror

I am trying to find which of the property are `vars` and which are `let`.

Using Mirroring I can get a object Child from which I can get a label, the value and the dynamic type of the value

```
    let mirrored_object = Mirror(reflecting: myObject)
    for property in mirrored_object.children {

        // Here I have property as Child
        // from which I can get 
        // property.label
        // property.value
        // property.value.dynamicType
    }
```

But this is the dynamicType, I mean...

```
    let myProperty: String? <--- Will return an optional
    let myProperty: String   <--- Will return .Some
```

but what I would like to detect is:

```
    var myProperty: String
```

vs

```
    let myProperty: String
```

Comment: What is the use case for this?

Comment: a test to assert that all the properties of my DTOs models are defined as `let`

Comment: There is no way that I know to determine `var` vs `let`. Tests are also not meant to force a coding style. Maybe a fancy Linter can help you with issues like this. Tests are meant to test State, Performance and UI.

Comment: [link to swift linter](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint)

Comment: In my opinion it is not a issue about of code styling, I am not testing the style of my code but testing it to guarantee that all the exposed objects are immutable, which is an important test for the public layer of a framework. It goes further than a style guide

Comment: Maybe coding "style" is not the correct wording, "design" is a better description. Doesn't make it testable. You also can't test for other design stuff. Like Singleton or Delegation Patterns. You could use a Linter....